# filament v3 Method Filament\Actions\CreateAction::table does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

````
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
 
CreateAction::make()
    ->model(Post::class)
    ->form([
        TextInput::make('title')
            ->required()
            ->maxLength(255),
        // ...
    ])```
````

```
composer require filament/actions:"^3.0-stable" -W
```

But it resulted in an error:

> Method Filament\Actions\CreateAction::table does not exist.
> Bad Method Call Did you mean Filament\Actions\CreateAction::disabled() ?

I tried this operation and also tried replacing the code examples with official examples, but both resulted in errors.

My code structure is as follows, and I've used // to omit some specific content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\BrowserResource\Pages;
use Filament\Actions\CreateAction;
use App\Models\Browser;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
 
 

class BrowserResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Browser::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationGroup = '流量源-Facebook';
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-window';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                //
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                //
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([])
            ->bulkActions([
                 //
            ])
            
            ->headerActions([
                
                CreateAction::make()
                    ->icon("heroicon-o-arrow-down-circle")
->model(Post::class)
                    ->form([
                        //
                    ])
                    ->action(function (array $data): void {
                    }),
 



            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListBrowsers::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateBrowser::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditBrowser::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }
}
```

I really don't understand where the error is coming from. I've already imported use Filament\Actions\CreateAction;, but it keeps saying it doesn't exist. I've even re-downloaded it.

This is my composer.json file:

```
  "filament/actions": "^3.0-stable",
        "filament/filament": "^3.0-stable",
        "filament/tables": "^3.0-stable",
```

I think the error should be like this.

Comment: Did you call `use Filament\Actions\CreateAction;` in top?

Comment: Yes, I've already updated it. I've referenced it in the code.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/actions/prebuilt-actions/create#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20add%20this%20action%20to%20the%20header%20of%20a%20table%20instead%2C%20you%20can%20use%20Filament%5CTables%5CActions%5CCreateAction%3A), you need to use `Filament\Tables\Actions\CreateAction` instead of `Filament\Actions\CreateAction` for table header actions.

Also, there's no need to require each filament package separately. Just require `filament/filament`, filament actions, tables, ... will be installed automatically.

Here's a full code of my test:

```php
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Forms;

...

public static function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->columns([
            //
        ])
        ->filters([
            //
        ])
        ->actions([])
        ->bulkActions([
            //
        ])

        ->headerActions([

            Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make()
                ->form([
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('title')
                        ->required()
                        ->maxLength(255),
                ]),

        ])
        ->emptyStateActions([]);
}
```